# os.walk() to match contents of a files from a CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, string-matching, os.walk

> I have two words i would like to search for using a CSV file, this is done using the os.walk() method to recursively look through each file within the `rootDir` however not too sure on what i'm missing to complete my code. The two words i am looking for is which are in two separate files:

```
XZOXNEOXXTWX, YOEYTWOYZYNY
```

To start off with i created a csv to look for certain words, i then have created the `os.walk()` method and tried reading the text from the CSV file to output the matching contents. I have looked through a fair bit of material but i want it not matching up to what i would like to output.

```
appendData = []
mPath = r"C:\Users\test\Documents\test"
wordstoSearch = r"C:\Users\test\Documents\test\strings.csv"

for rootDir, subDir, files in os.walk(mPath, topdown=True):
    print('Root Directory:', rootDir)
    for x in files: 
        with open(os.path.join(files)):
            with open ('strings.csv', 'rt') as stringSearch:
                if wordstoSearch in stringSearch.read():
                    appendData.append('File:   {}\nMatching Content: {}\n'.format(x, wordstoSearch))
appendData = '\n'.join(appendData)
print (appendData)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the words to check once using `csv` at the top of the script. Then be careful how you build the filename to check - you need to join the root directory to the filename. Finally, read each target file and then go through the list of words to check.

```
import csv

appendData = []
mPath = r"C:\Users\test\Documents\test"
wordstoSearch = r"C:\Users\test\Documents\test\strings.csv"

# get the words to check
with open(wordstoSearch) as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    words = [cell.strip() for cell in next(reader)]

# walk the tree
for rootDir, subDir, files in os.walk(mPath, topdown=True):
    print('Root Directory:', rootDir)
    for x in files: 
        with open(os.path.join(rootDir, x)) as check_fp:
            text = check_fp.read()
            for word in words:
                if word in text:
                    appendData.append(
                        'File:   {}\nMatching Content: {}\n'.format(x, word))
appendData = '\n'.join(appendData)
print (appendData)
```

Comment: builtins.AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'reader'

Comment: Do you have a script in the local directory called `csv.py`? It could be masking the one in python's library. Try `print(csv.__file__)` to see if its the standard one.

Comment: It is taking me back to where the script is saved rather than wordtoSearch csv file

Comment: Is that in answer to the `csv.__file__` question? Is your script named `csv.py`?

Comment: Yes but i dont understand why it is csv.py and not strings.csv

Comment: We are miscommunicating here... I asked you if your script is named "csv.py" and you said yes, but you don't know why its not named "strings.csv". Well... you named it! And it has to end  in .py. I'm confused!

Comment: My script is called findstrings.py but when i run your code it re-directs me to a file called csv.py. The file i created is in the location of C:\Users\test\Documents\test\strings.csv which has already been declared before the reader known as wordstoSearch. The  reader = csv.reader(fp) function gives the error of builtins.AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'reader' and shows the location of the csv.file which is not what i am trying to gain access to. The purpose of the word function was to search files and if a string matched from strings.csv it would output that string

Comment: If I understand, `print(csv.__file__)` prints just "csv.py". That means there is a file called `csv.py` in the current working directory. Even if your file is called "findstrings.py" there could still be another file in that same directory.

Comment: That is correct there is a csv file called csv.py but why the error, shouldnt it just output File: textexample.txt Matching Content: YOEYTWOYZYNY

Comment: When you `import csv` python looks in several directories for a file named `csv.py` and uses that. If you have `./csv.py`, it is imported instead of the standard one that comes with python. Your local `csv.py` file doesn't have a function called `reader`. You need to rename your local file.

Comment: I was not aware of the several directories search, the issue is now resolved i appreciate your efforts sir.

Comment: I have never liked this feature of python. It makes casual use easier when running scripts in the local directory but its just as easy to have a problem like this one.

Comment: Before asking i tried to solve the problem but had no idea why it kept redirecting me to the csv.py file. New to the CSV concept in python

Comment: This is a general module import issue - its not csv specific. If you have `os.py` or `time.py` or whatever in your local directory, you've masked the standard module. And the problem expands to any package you may install later. You just have to know which names to avoid and that's what makes it bad.

Comment: I will keep this in mind for next time thank you once again